# Create Query in Access via ADO.NET SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ado.net, oledb

What Syntax is used to create a query in Access SQL via ADO.NET (C# Application)?

```
CREATE QUERY [Q] AS SELECT...
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It's [CREATE VIEW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/create-view-statement-microsoft-access-sql)...

Comment: Thank you.  I don't know why that was so difficult to find.